# linux scp/sftp commands

Tags: linux, sftp, scp

I will be invoking these commands from Java using Jsch. I have been looking for good answers on the following questions that I have

1. Is there a limit on the size of the files being transferred remotely.
2. I know sftp commands can be interrupted as compared to scp . But what would be my options in the case of a network failure or some other interruption during a file transfer for both of those commands ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

1. No.
2. If the network fails, you'll have to restart the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no file size limits, but if you want your transfer to be failsafe, check out rsync instead.

http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/11/19/resume-scprsync-file-transfer/